# Show a note that comments will be held for moderation after comment expiration

Tags: comments, moderation

**How can i show a note to users when the commenting period is expired

(but commenting is not disabled)?**

Say, i allow 30 days for comments to be posted on an entry. 
Instead of disabling comments after this period, i have set the comment module to hold new comments for moderation
[user guide - moderate-expired-comments](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/control_panel/index.html#moderate-expired-comments)

on the front-end i would like to show a note that commenting has expired and that any new comments will be held for moderation. However, the [{if comments_expired}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/#comments-expired) conditional won't work because, as the manual says, it is overriden by the moderate expired comments settings.